# Approximation algorithm for graph problem

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, linear-programming

In the process of trying to create an approximation algorithm for the following problem.

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph, $c_e, c_{iv} \ge 0$, for $e \in E$, $i \in L$, and $v \in V$, where $L$ is a finite set of integers.  Each vertex $v$ in the graph is to be assigned an element $i$ from the list $L$ at cost $c_{iv}$.  Cost $c_e$ is incurred for an edge iff its vertices are in different lists.  The objective is to find the minimum cost assignment to vertices.

IP: Minimize $\sum_{e \in E} c_e x_e + \sum_{i \in L \\ v \in V} c_{iv}y_{iv}$
subject to

$\sum_{i \in L} y_{iv} = 1$ for all $v \in V$,

$y_{iv} + y_{ju} \le 1 + x_{(u,v)}$,
for all $(u,v) \in E$, $i \neq j \in L$.

$x_e, y_{iv} \in \{0,1\}$ for all $e \in E$, $i \in L$, $v \in V$.

Somehow (through rounding), I am supposed to use the linear relaxation to create a 2-factor approximation for the optimal solution to this integer program.  Does anyone have a hint for how to proceed?

Comment: first solve a sample instance and look at the LP relaxation solution. See if you can do some thing with that. My guess is at least one of the variables should take a value greater that 0.5. Fix that and solve it repeatedly. Let me know if this works. If so, then one could go ahead try proving it.

Comment: By fix it do you mean round it to one? A problem I've encountered is that the optimal solution to the LP could avoid charging any edge (for example, by setting $x_{iv} = \frac{1}{|L|}$ for all $i$, $v$).  Then, when I round, inevitably I will create conflicts which will incur edge costs.  So somehow I have to bound those ...

Comment: But you're right, it seems that at least the minimum $c_{iv}$ for each vertex $v$ should have $x_{iv}$ value at least 1/2. However, rounding all of those guys to 1 should create edge conflict. @pondy

Comment: Don't round all at one time. Round one in a single iteration. And keep doing it every iteration. That is why the method is called iterative LP rounding

Comment: What is the reason that you are interested in this problem?

Comment: It is an exercise to help me understand the role of linear programming in the design of approximation algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you specify is called *Uniform Labeling Problem* and often arises in the field of computer vision. Kleinberg & Tardos give the LP-based [2-approximation](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/focs99-mrf.pdf) you are looking for.

This problem also appears in the Williamson & Shmoys [book](http://www.designofapproxalgs.com) as exercise 5.10.